# Manage thousands of async calls to an API, but verify each one happened and returned

Tags: asp.net, .net, asynchronous

My app will need to pull down for example 60,000 tiles (images) from a remote web service.

In my current implementation I work out the 60,000 URLs for each map tile, I then loop through and request each one in sequence so I know I have them all.

You can imagine how slow this is, but as this is a tile server I can make multiple hits to the server simultaneously, but I need to make sure I get each of the 60,000 tiles.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

I was thinking of storing the URLs in a database table, each thread would grab a URL, set a flag in the table to taken, and when it's complete set another flag to complete that row.

I've not done any .Net Async programming before, how would you do it?

Comment: I would look at Tasks to do this with, as they are supposed to make async programming a lot easier (haven't used them yet myself).

Comment: you can implement multithreading to make multiple hits to the server. e.g. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyClass.GetTiles), new object[] { objArguements });`

Comment: take a look at Parallel.ForEach() from the Task Parallel Library. it enables data parallelism over any IEnumerable<T>, in your case, a list of 60k URLs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx